# how to use kafka dependency in spark streaming jar package instead of cluster dependencies?

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, dependencies, spark-streaming

i wanna to use spark streaming to write data into kafka topic. In order to ensure that the data written to kafka only appears once, i create producer in each executor with specific transaction.id. The question is that the `KafkaProducer` in spark-streaming-kafka dependency doesn't not have method like `initTransactions()`, so i need to use `KafkaProducer` in kafka-client dependency.

i've add the `KafkaProducer` in kafka-client into jar, however, when i run the jar, it still came out error like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.initTransactions()`. it seems that it still use the jar deployed on the spark cluster. what should i do to correct it? i'll appreciate it if you can do me a favor.